# JTable setting model and preserve column formats (width, alignment, etc.)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, model-binding

This is a brain-cracking experience with `JTable` binding. Here's what I did. I created a `JTable` with columns set to a specified width, formatted it using `renderers`, and added some codes on it. ***But when i try to bind it to a model, all the columns were replaced by the fields of the model***. Is there a way on how to correctly bind it?

I'm avoiding loops because there are 100+ thousand records in the database. I'm trying to use other methods such as `BeansBinding` and `EntityManager` but I don't know how to change the datasource (*that's why i choose binding it to a model*) because I'm testing this to backup database and soon to be implemented to the new server.

This is what I did in `.Net`, I usually create a datagridview and binded it to a dataset and it works fine. But i cannot apply it to java. I need your opinion on how can I do it in java that can handle 100+ thousand records.

```
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("SQL Query here");
    ResultSet rs = pst.ExecuteQuery();
    jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

The code above works fine but my very very big problem on this is that it overrides my formatted columns by the columns in the model.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Is DbUtils written by you? Did you develop the table model yourself? In this case you could add a setResultSet(rs) method and trigger the model events to update the table. That would probably keep the columns intact.

Comment: @dsboger no, actually i got it from here: http://technojeeves.com/joomla/index.php/free/59-resultset-to-tablemodel it's a jar file.

Comment: You can create a method updateTableModelFromResultSet(tModel, rs) that is similar to resultSetToTableModel(rs), but calls tModel.setDataVector(rows) to update the data. If you need a help with the code I can turn this into an answer.

Comment: I just noticed that setDataVector changes the columns, so it probably won't work. Another way is to clear the model with tModel.setRowCount(0) add the rows directly using tModel.addRow.

Comment: @dsboger how can you do that? can you please show me? basically i new to java environment that's why i need help on this. :(

Comment: I posted an answer with some code. That may solve the problem with the column formatting, but I suggest you read the article linked by @mKorbel in his answer as it can lead to a faster implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, you could try to add the following method to DbUtils:

```
public static void updateTableModelData(DefaultTableModel tModel, ResultSet rs) 
        throws Exception {
    tModel.setRowCount(0);
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

    while (rs.next()) {
        Vector newRow = new Vector();
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
            newRow.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
        }
        tModel.addRow(newRow);
    }
}
```

and then your code would became:

```
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("SQL Query here");
ResultSet rs = pst.ExecuteQuery();
DbUtils.updateTableModelData((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel(), rs);
```

Answer (score 2):

too wide question

1) never, really never put `100+ thousand records` to the view, and this is valid for all programing languages, is really useless

2) (my view) BeansBindings are out_dated use standard TableModel instead

3) nothing better as @camickr [TableFromDatabase](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) is around, or another suggestion is searching for `ResultSetTableModel`

Answer (score 0):

l have discovered that you can create your formatting method and call it after the try block as below.

```
 private void UpdateTable() throws SQLException {
     String sql = "select * from invoice";
    proDialog.setValue(10);
    table.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
    table.setShowVerticalLines(true);
    proDialog.setValue(20);
    try (
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);

          ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

            )
            {           
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));          
    } catch (Exception e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    format();       
}

public void format() {
TableColumnModel m = table.getColumnModel();
m.getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(FormatRenderer.getDateTimeRenderer());
m.getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(FormatRenderer.getTimeRenderer());
m.getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(NumberRenderer.getPercentRenderer());
m.getColumn(4).setCellRenderer(NumberRenderer.getCurrencyRenderer());
m.getColumn(4).setCellRenderer(NumberRenderer.getPercentRenderer());
m.getColumn(5).setCellRenderer(NumberRenderer.getCurrencyRenderer());
}
```

This will work perfectly