# Ordering JTable entried by Date

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, date, jtable

There is JTable, and one of columns has Date format. I need to sort table entries according to this column (Date).

To solve this task, I created a class TableSorter (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableSorterDemoProject/src/components/TableSorter.java). Then I added the following lines in the code:

```
TableSorter sorter = new TableSorter(tableModel);
sorter.setTableHeader(table.getTableHeader());
```

When I run the program, I can see only small triagles added to headers, but ordering does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to add `TableSorter` to the `TableModel` as is described in the [JTables tutorial about Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Comment: It helps me as well. Sir do you have idea on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599474/jtable-setting-model-and-preserve-column-formats-width-alignment-etc