# How to Add ResultSet Data To JTable with out changing Default Colomn names of jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, resultset

I have the following class:

```
public class customer_master extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {

    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    JFrame parent;
    public customer_master(JFrame parent) {

        this.parent=parent;
        initComponents();

        try {
            String qry="select customer_code, customer_name, customer_address, customer_created_time from customer";
            database.JavaConnect jc= new JavaConnect(); 
            con = jc.ConnectDB();
            ps = con.prepareStatement(qry);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            con.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }    
}
```

It also change the name of columns but I want to add rs without changing columns name please if any one can help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Kapil.  Please considering adding more information to your question.  What is the class you've included, what is its purpose?  What is your final goal?  What is an example of the output you are seeing?  The more information you can provide, the easier it is for others to help.  It is difficult when just a class is given to go on.

Comment: i admit i have not provided full info..... i was asking for a simple solution that does not change default jTable Column name with metadata from database table.... //** DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs) **// this function was replacing default column name with table metadata....  but i was keep searching and i found solution on here.... ****http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599474/jtable-setting-model-and-preserve-column-formats-width-alignment-etc**** thank you for  support. thank you very much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question implies that you are refeshing and existing JTable with a new ResultSet. So when you create the JTable the first time and assign names to each column you need to add:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...);
table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel( false );
```

This will tell the table not to recreate the TableColumnModel so all the columns and custom renderers and editors will remain.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your query

> String qry="select customer_code, customer_name, customer_address, 
>                customer_created_time from customer";

to

> String qry="select customer_code ***AS Customer Code***, customer_name ***AS Customer Name***, customer_address ***AS Customer Address***, 
>                customer_created_time ***AS DOJ*** from customer";

and you'll be good to go.